# ValueError: Cannot assign "(<User: testuser>,)": "Message.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

Trying to create a simple real-time chat application with multiple chat rooms. When trying to add new message in the message model, getting ValueError.

The `model.py`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The `view.py`:

```
def addMessage(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username']),
    room = Room.objects.get(id = request.POST['room_id']),
    message = request.POST['message'],
    Message.objects.create(
        user = user,
        room = room,
        body = message
    )
    return HttpResponse("Message Sent Sucessfully!")
```

I have seen many similar questions, but none of the solutions worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added trailing commas in the following lines

```py
user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username']),
room = Room.objects.get(id = request.POST['room_id']),
message = request.POST['message'],
```

These variables become a python [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and result in the error since the values are wrong types.

Remove those trailing commas should fix the issue.

```py
user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username'])
room = Room.objects.get(id = request.POST['room_id'])
message = request.POST['message']
```